# Laravel DatabaseTransactions trait and autocommit=1

Tags: database, laravel-5, eloquent

Currently in order to use `DatabaseTransactions` in my tests, I have to turn off `autocommit` in MySQL settings. However, it makes `$model->save()` stop working (no data was saved to database). What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, you basically tell the database to not insert anything, until you commit the transaction. So your models are saving fine. But the database is not writing the inserts/updates in the data files. Its waiting for you to tell it when to do it by issuing a COMMIT statement.

To fix it you should not turn off autocommit, but properly use transactions.

See my article for how to properly use database transactions in Laravel at:
http://lesichkov.co.uk/article/20150927110905758776/laravel-5-database-transactions